# How do I inherit a specific cell option from another style (without copy paste)?

Tags: stylesheet, inheritance

How can I define a style with `FontSize` from **Section** and `CellFrame` from **Program**?

Answer (score 8):

### Update

I must have read *fontstyle* instead of *fontsize* in your question. Therefore, the approach below shows how to use the complete style of **Section** with the frame of **Program**. To achieve what you want, just create a new style and copy *any* style properties (e.g. `FontSize` and `CellFrame`) from any existing style with the method I explain below.

**Sidenote:** To inherit a style, it's not necessary to copy anything. You can just use

```
Cell[StyleData["MySec",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]], ...]
```

as explained by Mike in the comments.

### Original answer

Go to *Format -> Edit Stylesheet...* and click on the `Default.nb` link in the upper left corner. There you go to *Style for Title and Section Cells* and click on the Section. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or go to *Cell -> Show Expression* and copy the whole `Cell` expression. Afterwards you can close the cell expression with the same shortcut again.

**Note:** When you only want to reuse an existing style, you can just copy the cell without showing the cell expression. I only explained it because we need it in the following and show, what you really copy.

Now you go into your empty local stylesheet and create a new style by entering a name into the text box on top of the page. Click on your created style cell and open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Paste the contents of the section definition there

[image]

Be carefull, that you remove the first line of the original Section cell, so that only your

```
Cell[StyleData["MySec"],
```

stays.

Now, you do equivalent steps to copy the `CellFrame` definition from the *Programm* style and replace the one in your new style with it.

That's it:

[image]

Comment: I didn't read his question that way. BTW you can just do `Cell[StyleData["MySec",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]], ...]` to inherit from section style.

Comment: Now that you say it, I don't read the question that way either. I have read *fontstyle* instead of *fontsize*.. :-(

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for your answer. I already knew about copying and pasting, that's why I asked this question: I was hoping for something like FontSize -> Inherit["Section"]

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
  CellPrint[Cell["text", 
   FontColor -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section", "FontColor"}], 
   FontFamily -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section", "FontFamily"}],
   FontSize -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section", "FontSize"}] ,
   CellFrame ->CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Program", "CellFrame"}], 
   Background -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "PrintUsage", "Background"}]]]
```

?

[image]

Comment: That's pretty slick.  Be aware that these styles are not dynamic; if you change the style sheet the style of the generated cell does not change with it.